# Shell based time and date formatting - can't add in more than a few string literals

Tags: regex, bash, shell, date, sed

I cobbled this together based on the man page, just skimming it though:

```
$date +'%m.%d.%Y'\ "%r"\ %z
05.03.2015 12:54:11 PM -0700
```

This gives:

```
05.03.2015 12:54:11 PM -0700
```

which is as close as I can get to what I want:

```
05.03.2015 - 12:54:11 PM -0700
```

I can't seem to get the en dash in the middle.  I can use a space like I have above if I escape it; looks like a `%` literal is done by escaping the percent with another percent e.g.: `%%`

There is a `%n` for newline, and a very few other modifiers.  How do I concatenate the two delimited by a en dash?

And I would love to do this all in the date formatting like I can do in other languages.  I really don't want to have to pipe to sed or awk or replace the first space with the " - ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably best to (single-) quote the entire format string as one, rather than mixing single-quotes, double-quotes and backslash escaping as you have.  I certainly think that's the clearest way to write it:

```
date +'%m.%d.%Y - %r %z'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm puzzled you had any problems.  Testing on a Mac (10.10.3), I simply included the en-dash in the format string, typing:

```
$ date +'%m.%d.%Y – %r %z'
05.03.2015 – 04:24:26 PM -0700
$ date +'%m.%d.%Y – %r %z' | utf8-unicode
(standard input):
0x30 = U+0030
0x35 = U+0035
0x2E = U+002E
0x30 = U+0030
0x33 = U+0033
0x2E = U+002E
0x32 = U+0032
0x30 = U+0030
0x31 = U+0031
0x35 = U+0035
0x20 = U+0020
0xE2 0x80 0x94 = U+2013
0x20 = U+0020
0x30 = U+0030
0x34 = U+0034
0x3A = U+003A
0x32 = U+0032
0x34 = U+0034
0x3A = U+003A
0x34 = U+0034
0x33 = U+0033
0x20 = U+0020
0x50 = U+0050
0x4D = U+004D
0x20 = U+0020
0x2D = U+002D
0x30 = U+0030
0x37 = U+0037
0x30 = U+0030
0x30 = U+0030
0x0A = U+000A
$
```

I simply included the en-dash in the format string.  Now, this is in a UTF-8 terminal, so maybe that accounts for some of the difference.  And I happen to know the key sequence for en-dash (–) and em-dash (—) on the Mac keyboard (<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>, where <kbd>-</kbd> is the 'hyphen-minus' key).  If you're not on a Mac, the key sequences will be different.

Note that I avoid having to escape spaces by including them all inside the single quotes around the format string argument.  The position of the first quote is 'cosmetic'; the shell removes it whether it is there or `date '+%m.…'` and `date` never sees the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.  I merely had to escape the spaces, which I tried, but for some reason, didn't work right away.  As you will see, it is  a mess, which is where I screwed it up. but it works now, and I think it is correct too.  I dropped the trailing "g" global modifier as I only wanted the first space edited/altered:

```
 $date +'%m.%d.%Y'\ "%r"\ %z | sed s/\ /\ -\ /
 >05.03.2015 - 01:06:39 PM -0700
```

Comment: Other contributors have posted much better solutions than mine. I have moved to using the simple solution of just quoting the entire command which works perfectly.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the dash `-` with space immediately after `%Y` so that it remains inside the quote:

```
date +'%m.%d.%Y -'\ "%r"\ %z
```

Comment: The backslashes and so on are really not necessary; it is much better to simply enclose the whole format string in quotes — single or double quotes will do in this context, though I'd use single quotes as they're generally more reliable (in other contexts) — and not need to escape spaces etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yap. Those answers are already given by others, so I just wanted the OP to know how he can do it with the smallest modification of his code.